# Skinnedbutton Plugin issue in win 7 -64 bit

Tags: nsis, skinning

I am using SkinnedButton-v1.2.zip (23 KB) - v1.2 by Slappy for skinning my installer buttons.

Its working fine everywhere except on Windows 7 64bit where the buttons are not showing image, neither the text the like 'Back, next , cancel' its just showing white buttons.

There is no skin button error coming up, however buttons are enabled and can be clicked.

Any idea what is the cause of this Issue?

Comment: This is strange, can you post your script? I actually tested this (my :) plug-in on Win7 x64 with no problems.

Comment: Sorry I cant share the whole script due to privacy issues of the company project, but I can tell you what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved using patched SkinnedControls plugin from [here](http://forums.winamp.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=45529&d=1243103729).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible errors:

1) Initialization function of installer is called **.onInit** (your is '.onint')

That means the $PLUGINSDIR is never initialized and file is not extracted.

2) Your Function *myGuiInit* is nowhere called/initialized.

You should define symbol MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT for this function, example:

```
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT "myGuiInit"
```

The best place to define this is somewhere at the beginning of script - near other MUI_ stuff.

Comment: Oh those were just typos. I am sharing a demo script which is also using your skinnedbutton plugin and is also not working with Win 7 64Bit.

Answer (score 0):

I run the plug-in in Debug mode and I found out that there is problem with

```
SetWindowLong() and GetWindowLong()
```

functions.

Maybe using SetWindowLongPtr and GetWindowLongPtr could solve this.
They take/return a LONG_PTR variable which is set depending on the compiler. It is a 32 bit long on x86 and a 64 bit _int64 on x64.

So the plug-in must be fixed and rebuild to support x64 machines. But because this plug-in is really outdated (at this moment I have no time for new version), please rather try my other tool/plug-in called **Graphical Installer**: http://www.graphical-installer.com/

I have developed this solution to quickly skin NSIS installers, I hope you will like it (sorry for self promo).

Comment: Well the thing is that I am not even using SetWindowLong() and GetWindowLong() in my script, so the issue may be something else. And its not working in windows 8 - 64 bit as well.
well I would love to use your Graphical Installer if it was free. ;) Cant afford it otherwise. Sorry.